# Existence of life using sulfur instead of oxygen

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, life

All life on earth (or at least most of them) require oxygen, at least to form the organic molecules that build up life. We know that sulfur has similar chemical properties. Organic compounds that contain sulfur are called **organosulfur compounds** and can be found in garlics, onions etc.

**Question**: Can any life use sulfur instead of oxygen? Like H<sub>2</sub>S instead of water, ethanethiol instead of alcohol, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sulfidation**

As mentioned [here](https://www.corrosionpedia.com/definition/1047/sulfidation),

> Sulfidation is a chemical reaction of a solid substance, such as a
> metal or an alloy, with sulfur in some form in its working
> environment. This produces compounds of sulfur that usually form on
> the solid surface or under the surface of the substance, such as a
> metal or alloy. Sulfidation most often causes serious deterioration of
> the solid surface and the vital functional properties of the affected
> substance.

**Corrosive**

As mentioned [here](https://www.slb.com/well-production/production-chemicals/cure-technologies/cure-hydrogen-sulfide-liquid-scavengers)

> Hydrogen sulfide (H2S) is very toxic and corrosive even at low levels.
> The occupational exposure limit is 10 ppm and the gas is fatal above
> 150 ppm. Corrosion due to H2S can lead to catastrophic failures, which
> may occur without warning.

**Liquid phase**

Boiling point of H2S is -60°C and freezing point is -85.5°C. Your life form should be living at around -70°C.

**Deterioration**

Sulfur and hydrogen sulfide are very corrosive to metals, concrete and many other materials. Environment full of Sulfur and hydrogen sulfide will deteriorate very soon.

Comment: The H2S toxicity is of course relative to life forms based on H2O (water). Chances are that any H2S-based life would find H2O rather toxic for the same reasons - chemically similar, but not similar enough.

Comment: @MSalters Water is also corrosive. It's just that we have learned to handle it. In a world were H2S is prevalent, and water isn't, they would find water corrosion more difficult to handle that H2S corrosion (that would be everyday, I know how to handle,  problem)

Comment: The toxicity point assumes a biochemistry identical to ours, which is directly ruled-out by the very premise of the question, the mention of corrosion seems a bit short sighted, given that _water_ is corrosive as well, and the phase issue is only an issue if we require such life to exist under standard earth-like conditions (which may not be the case).

Comment: It's a good thing the planet is cold. On most planets, water will be far more abundant than any sulfur compound. If it isn't locked into a solid state, life will probably end up evolving to prefer it as a solvent.

Answer (score 11):

Anaerobic life using sulfur has already been discovered and [documented](https://academic.oup.com/femsre/article/22/5/353/497009?login=false). It uses sulfur as oxidative species, instead of oxygen.

However this sort of life still relies on having water available as main solvent. [$H_2S$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide) cannot act as water substitute, for the simple reason that it is a gas in the same conditions where water is liquid.

> Hydrogen sulfide is a chemical compound with the formula $H_2S$. It is a colorless chalcogen-hydride **gas**, and is poisonous, corrosive, and flammable, with trace amounts in ambient atmosphere having a characteristic foul odor of rotten eggs

Comment: Definitely i know that H2S is a gas under __room temperature__. What if the temperature is below the boiling point of H2S?

Comment: @SketchySketch: At normal pressure, [hydrogen sulfide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_sulfide) boils at −60 °C and freezes at −82 °C.

Comment: Sulfur based life used to exist fairly predominantly on earth. https://www.popsci.com/science/article/2011-08/oldest-fossils-ever-found-could-present-new-target-search-extraterrestrial-life/ This article has other relevant links in it.

Comment: [H2S is a liquid at 70F and 252 psi](https://www.concoa.com/hydrogen_sulfide_properties.html#:~:text=Hydrogen%20sulfide%20is%20a%20colorless,250%20psig%20%40%2070%C2%B0%20F.)  which is 17 atmospheres pressure.  That is well under the atmospheric pressure of Venus.